# How to use Mongoose find to perform geo spatial queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am creating an app with two entities, Book and User.

I added a parameter in the User entity schema called locationCoords which contains the array with coordinates related with the User itself (longitude first).

```
locationCoords: {
    type: [Number],
    index: '2d'
}
```

when looking for a Book, I try to show results coming from User in the nearby.
So, I would like to perform a find query like this

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
    if(req.user) {
        Book.find({'user.locationCoords': {'$near': req.user.locationCoords}}).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName locationName locationCoords').exec(function(err, books) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.jsonp(books);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I created entries with nearby locations, but the query does not return any result.
Any suggestion?

I am using the schema below

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Book title',
        trim: true
    },
    language: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Book language',
        trim: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Book image',
        trim: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

Thanks
Regards
Maurizio

Comment: Is the `user` embedded or referenced by `Book`? Keep in mind that MongoDB only allows you to query for fields on embedded subdocuments, not on referenced one.

Comment: @Philipp This is inside the schema for the Book 
 user: {
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User'
 } How am I supposed to query it?

Comment: @Philipp If that is the case, how do I perform the query that I need?